# XCode 4 Generating classes from entities in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, xcode4

Im using XCode 4 and working with CoreData. Now, how do I generate classes for entities? I used to do it in XCode 3 by clicking on a diagram entity, going to File->New and choosing NSManagedObject class.

For some reason i cant seem to find it in XCode 4, it's not showing up in the dialog...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find in DP5 it is now a menu item. Finally!

Comment: I'm assuming this is referring to opening the xcdatamodel and navigating to Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass.

Comment: @AdamE I got it done with help of the answer below. I didn't get your answer. What is DP5? Just curios.

Comment: Many answers here are as dated as a "Master Visual Basic 6 in 30 Days" book - this is an example :-) I think I was referring to Xcode 4 Developer Preview 5, which was new and exciting in 2010. Fortunately as of Xcode 6 this hasn't changed.

Answer (score 24):

[image: Add NSManagedObject Subclass]

If you are new to Xcode (like me) some graphics to make it easier to explain. Just make sure that you select the entities that you want before you click on "Create NSManagedObject Subclasss"

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by making the entity CLASS the same as the entity NAME, i.e. "Person" instead of "NSManagedObject".  I also noticed that I have to invoke File > New File twice (!)  The first time, the Managed Object Class template is not available, but the second time it is. No clue why.
 I'm running XCode 3.2.4.

Comment: Thanks but mate im talking about xcode 4. There is a big difference 3.2.4 and 4 and yeah. ill try your suggestion and see how it goes though and let you and everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

While editing your xcdatamodel you need to select the entity and make sure the right hand Utilities pane is open. Select the Data Model Inspector (the tab on the right) and you can set the class of your entity to whatever you want.